# How to set the blend mode for a semi-transparent window?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, directx, unreal-engine5

How to set the blend mode for a semi-transparent window to overlay on the desktop? Actually just an static image, no UI. Like in Photoshop (Hue, Multiply, Screen, Soft Light, etc)?

In the example below, the Difference blend mode:

[image: example]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have the source code. I am looking for a solution here. Not necessarily a finished code, at least a description of the approach.

Comment: You'd first need to capture an image of what's under your window, then blend that with your image for display (directX effects I seem to recall have something you can use directly). The part I don't know offhand is getting the pixels under your window. So, perhaps split your question into two parts for the separate subproblems.